# Should we restrict drunk people to enter the temple?

Tags: karma, dharma

I am asking this question because this incident has happened to me. 
Actually, I have restricted one of my friends to enter the temple because he has taken the drink outside the **Bherunath mandir Ujjain** without offering the alcohol to the god (**Bherunath Ujjain**).

My question is that what I have done is right or not, I have restricted one of my friends to enter the temple of the **Mangalnath mandir Ujjain**? After restricted him I am not feeling well that What I have done is right or not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97058/discussion-on-question-by-ravindra-kushwaha-should-we-restrict-drunk-people-to-e).

Comment: @TheDestroyer "My question is that what I have done is right or not" - This is a personal advice question so needs to be closed.

Comment: @sv. As your wish man!!!

Comment: Not my wish, those are the site rules. See [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296). @Ravindra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temple is called the [Devalaya or the "abode of God"](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=devalaya&direct=se&anz=100). That's why we don't enter it while we are not pure.

Now, drinking alcohol makes one impure. It is considered in the Hindu scriptures as one of the great sins.

> Manu Smriti 9.235. The slayer of a Brahmana, (A twice-born man) who
>   drinks (the spirituous liquor called) Sura, he who steals (the gold of
>   a Brahmana), and he who violates a Guru’s bed, must each and all be
>   considered as men who committed mortal sins (mahapataka).

Also, see the following passage from the [Kurma Purana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kurmapurana-11.htm):

> A person who kills a brahmana, drinks wine, or steals gold from a
>   brahmana, has to perform penance by killing himself. A person who
>   kills a brahmana may also build a hut in the forest and live there for
>   a period of twelve years. But throughout the period, he has to bear a
>   mark signifying the dead brahmana’s head on his palm. **He is also not
>   permitted to visit another brahmana or a temple as long as the penance
>   is going on.**

See the bold portion. He should not enter a temple because he does not regain purity unless the penance is complete. This shows that one must not enter temples or any holy places while in an impure state.
So, from your side it was a good Karma done if you have informed him with the correct information and asked him not to enter the temple.

However, if devotion is high, then such restrictions may not matter and in those cases it is better not to come in between the God and his devotee. Let them deal with it.

Comment: However, if devotion is high, then such restrictions may not matter and in those cases it is better not to come in between the God and his devotee. Let them deal with it. = Perfect answer!!!

Comment: So you mean we can't enter untill we pure again by doing penance. But who can do penance in today's time? If one drank alcohol then he can never enter in temple until he don't do penance? Means almost half of the  men population are not allowed to enter in temple? Since sansarik human can't do penance.

Comment: No, you have to simply take a bath. Penance is not required. @Rishabh

Comment: Thanks for your input @Rickross

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Please provide me chat link where we can discuss

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha No problem :) Please keep participating on the site.

Comment: At the end, the conclusion is that if we are impure(drinking), we should not go to the temple. @Rickross

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

This is the chatroom!

Comment: But where is your given verse says we can get pure again by taking bath? Your answer doesn't give answer of OP's Q. completely.

Comment: Bathing is done to gain physical purity. Do I need to provide a verse for that? :) @Rishabh  .. after you have done a hair cut, an oil massage, evacuated bowels, drank or even ate something you are not considered ritually clean. One need to take bath in those circumstances.

Comment: @rickross But why need physical purity in the first place? Inner purity not enough? Besides how physical purity even matters if alcohol gone inside our body. It is inside our body, and bathing won't remove that alcohol from inside, Then how one can be pure by bathing? As per my understanding. SO this is just your opinion that bathing will pure drinking alcohol effect.

Comment: But still bathing is recommended to regain purity. Both internal and external purity matter. Ottherwise why people are required to bath everyday? Bahyabhyantara suchi means internal+external purity. Also, if you want to do the whole thing internally then why would you visit a temple? It is not required for you, you can do the prayer by being where you are. @Rishabh See this mantra: https://greenmesg.org/stotras/vishnu/om_apavitrah_pavitro_va.php

Comment: @rickross This is what I said.... If one had alcohol then take bath and then go to temple is just an opinion of your. For real, bathing can't remove alcohol that you drank. If alcohol still inside then bathing or no bathing, what does that matter? And we don't need to take bath to just meet our beloved Lord. Here real Q. is, how bathing can remove tamsic bhojana from inside of our body?

Comment: If one desperately wants to meet God after taking alcohol then its their choice. But it is not recommended. Any religious activity is a success only if its done with (internal+external) purity. @Rishabh

Comment: Also going by your logic we can never be pure because urine and faeces are always present in our body or being created, but still bathing and various other cleansing procedures are recommended in our scriptures. @Rishabh Also, my answer does not say that if one has drank then he has to bath and then enter the temple. Its simply saying that after drinking one should not enter temples.

Comment: @Rickross Is it opinon based question..Than next time i need to thing 10 times before asking question here .I have asked about the religion question

Comment: It is not a serious issue. You are a new user here so you may not know how to frame the same Q in different ways to prevent closure. When we were new all of us faced similar situations. If you ask "Is it the right thing for me?" or "Have I done the right thing?" then people tend to close them as opinion-based because it seems that you are asking for users' opinions. But if you frame the Qs in this manner "Does Hinduism allow drunk men entering temples? Do Hindu scriptures allow such an act?" Then you are basically asking the same thing in different manner and such Qs can't be closed.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha See the above comment. Also we are here to make necessary adjustments to prevent Qs from getting closed. So you need not worry. ask whatever you want ask. Gradually with more time spent on the site you will yourself learn what to ask and what not to on this site.

Comment: What determines whether devotion is high or not ? How does an ordinary soul determine whether the devotion of another soul to bhagwan is high

Comment: How much devotion a person A has towards his Ishta can not be judged by another person. It's a personal thing best known to A and his Ishta Devta. A person B, who knows that A is visiting temples after consuming forbidden articles, thus can only inform A that it is wrong to do so because B is aware of scriptures and B is worried about the well being of A. Further interference is not desired. That's the import of my answer.@Carmensandiego